# Change the monotonicity of a function but preserve its convexity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Consider the function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined as
$$
f(x) = \exp(x) + \exp(y)
$$
$f$ is convex in $(x,y)$ and it is strictly monotone increasing in $(x,y)$ (in the sense that, if $x_1 < x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$, then $f(x_1,y_1) < f(x_2,y_2)$). Does there exist a  function $g$ such that

1. $g$ is invertible.
2. The composition $g \circ f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is convex and strictly monotone *decreasing* in $(x,y)$.
3. $g(1) = 1$.

If condition 3 is too strict, I'm willing to drop it.

Comment: Surely $g(t) = -t$ will suffice?

Comment: @copper.hat $g(t) = -t$ violates condition 2, since $(g \circ f)(x) = -\exp(x) - \exp(y)$, which is concave and strictly monotone decreasing. I'm looking for a $g$ such that the composition $g \circ f$ is *convex* and strictly monotone decreasing. Also, $g(1) = -1$, which violates condition 3.

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly and was looking for a convex g.